# Facing issues in downloading cucumber plugin for Eclipse Oxygen 4.7

Tags: plugins, cucumber

When i try to install Cucumber plugin for Eclipse via Help install new 
software option, am getting the below error message,

```
 URL used to install  plugin: 
 'https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cucumber-eclipse-plugin'
  ##Unable to read repository at##
  [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxJW1.jpg
```

please guide me how to install cucumber plugin in eclipse to proceed with my automation scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the link that you added is correct? I tried the same and got an error that this is not a valid repository location. You can check it by clicking on Details button in the window.

To install it, go to **Help** > **Eclipse Marketplace** > then enter 'cucumber' in **Find** textbox and click on **Go** button. You will see Cucumber Eclipse Plugin and you can install it from there. Please try it out and let us know if it helps.

Also, for setting up cucumber, its not necessary that you add this plugin. If you are looking for cucumber setup with selenium, you can check out this tutorial as well (this one doesnt use the cucumber plugin) - [Cucumber Selenium Tutorial](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-selenium-testing-tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable feedback... I had created new cucumber project referring the tutorial which you had provided. but when i add the feature file, i dint get any pop up. Also it just appear like plain text file. When i check for Natural 0.7.6 in market place, i could not find any plugin in that name. Could you please help me to proceed further on this?